# how do it associate a dropdown-menu input to another databasetable with laravel

Tags: database, laravel, drop-down-menu, associative

I've got a form that fills a table in my database. Now i've added a dropdown to that form where the you can choose a user that should be associated to the rest of the form input. But im still unable to associate the dropdown to the user_id in the table.

I hope i made my issue clear,

Comment: Need to provide code.

Comment: Please provide the code in your controller, view and model

Comment: Thank you both for your reply but i just got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The code that i just in my controller was :

public function store(PartRequest $request)
    {
        Project::find(Input::get('project'))->parts()->create($request->all());
        return redirect('parts');
    }

where my dropdown had classname:project